# Grails Spring Security get assigned roles to a method

Tags: security, grails, functional-testing

I would like to have a test that goes through all methods available in a controller and retrieves roles associated with these methods. I understand that it should be a functional test (as opposed to a unit test), but I still do not know how to request the list of roles associated with a method.
Let's say I have this controller:

```
@Secured("hasAnyRole('ROLE_1')"
class MyController {
    def methodA() {}

    @Secured("hasAnyRole('ROLE_2')"
    def methodB() {}
 }
```

In my test I would like to have something like this:

```
assertEquals(['ROLE_1'],getRoles(MyController.class, "methodA"))
assertEquals(['ROLE_1', 'ROLE_2'],getRoles(MyController.class, "methodB"))
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Something like:

```
Method m = MyController.class.getMethod("methodB");
Annotation[] annos = m.getAnnotations();
```

<strike>But I don't think that's a good validation for your method, since it only ensure that you write the role name correctly. I think it's better you try to call the action and check if the process redirect to denied.</strike>

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerTests {
  @Test
  void shouldRedirectToDenied() {
    SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth('username') {
      controller.methodB()
      assert controller.response.redirectedUrl == '/login/denied'
    }
  }
}
```

The `doWithAuth` closure will mock an authentication for the username, so it's the same to say: "do this code as if the username was logged in successfully".

It seems that you will need to use functional tests indeed. See Burt's comment. I'm still think that's not a valid effort create a test only to validate if the method have the annotation.

Comment: Spring Security isn't active in integration tests since it's implemented with a filter chain, and the requests are just `MockHttpServletRequest`s, not real requests running in a container. If you want to test that a controller is guarded correctly you have to use functional tests.

Comment: I understand that I need functional test, but I still do not know how if it is possible to get the list of roles for a function, as opposed to try to authenticate a user first and then try to access a function.

Comment: You can get the list of annotatios an his values through the Java Reflection API. I had striked that, but check my edit (3 first lines).